# enable apache webdav logs for webdav operations

Tags: apache, webdav

I need access to my webdav logs for check GET and POST operations, in my old apache setup I could find them in this file: **/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log**

unfortunately my new apache setup (in other machine) is not generating me these logs, I've checked the *LogLevel* inside **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf** but both files seems *practically identical*, apache webdav has other file configuration for logs reporting?

thanks

Comment: Have you upgraded from Apache 2.2 to 2.4? A number of changes were made to the logging configuration in 2.4

Comment: hi @SteveE. yes both servers are running apache 2.4, do you know how config the logs for apache webdav?..thanks!

Comment: Webdav should still log access requests using the 'CustomLog' config option. It's hard to guess what is missing from your config to make this happen. Have you tried adding an entry into the context with `Dav On`. E.g. underneath `Dav On` Add `CustomLog /var/log/apache2/webdav_access.log common`. This assumes that folder exists and is writable by apache?